# Ignore leading indentation inside vue-markdown tag

Tags: vue.js, markdown

Using the `vue-markdown` plugin, if I have code like this:

```
        <div class="col">
            <vue-markdown>
              ## Hello
            </vue-markdown>
```

It renders like:

```
## Hello
```

In order to have the markdown treated as a heading I need to do this:

```
        <div class="col">
            <vue-markdown>
## Hello
            </vue-markdown>
```

Is there a way to have leading indentation ignored?

Comment: can you share any live demo ? or snippet ? [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/0dzvcf4d/19750/)

Comment: Looks like a known limitation: see issues [vue-markdown#56](https://github.com/miaolz123/vue-markdown/issues/56) and [vue-markdown#69](https://github.com/miaolz123/vue-markdown/issues/69) which proposes a wrapper component as workaround.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Want to make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution [*temporary*] from the comment of [@ghybs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5108796/ghybs)

Looks like a known limitation: see issues

- [vue-markdown # 56](https://github.com/miaolz123/vue-markdown/issues/56)

and

- [vue-markdown # 69](https://github.com/miaolz123/vue-markdown/issues/69)

which proposes to wrapper component as workaround.